# grails - my log4j configuration doesn't produce any output

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm trying to use log4j in my webapp, I wrote a log4j configuration based on the exemple in [this](http://grails-dev.blogspot.fr/2012/09/setting-up-log4j-configuration-in.html) blog.

Files are created but there is no ouput. I tried different configurations without success

**Config.groovy**

```
def log4jFileName = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base', '.') + "/logs/myapp.log"
def log4jStacktrace = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base', '.') + "/logs/stacktrace.log"

environments {
    development {
        log4jFileName = "logs/myapp.log"
    }
    test {
        log4jFileName = "logs/myapp.log"
    }
}

log4j = {
    def pattern = new PatternLayout("[%p] [%c{3}] %m%n")

    appenders {
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                        name:"file",
                        file:log4jFileName,
                        layout: pattern,
                        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                        threshold: Level.toLevel("DEBUG")
                    )

        rollingFile name:"stacktrace",
            file:log4jStacktrace,
            maxFileSize:'5MB',
            layout: pattern,
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"

        console name:"stdout",
                layout: pattern,
                datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    }

    root { 
        environments {
            production {
                debug "file", "stacktrace"
            }
            development {
                debug "file", "stdout"
            }
        }
    }

    error   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    warn    'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'grails.plugins.springsecurity',
            'groovyx.net.http'

    debug   'grails.app'

}
```

**Controller**

```
log.info("info")
log.error("error")
log.debug("debug")
log.warn("warn")
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code which call to print log?

Comment: You may want to use -Dlog4j.debug to check log4j then.